# Не выходит получить данные ни одного элемента на странице в фигме

Tags: html, css, figma

Я новичок в верстке. Хочу попробовать сейчас сверстать сайт. Его макет есть в фигме, но даже после того как я включила dev mode и duplicate не получается получить данные ни одного элемента на странице. Я нажимаю на них, но вижу только слои, а не цвет чего-то, например, или ширину и т.д. Может, кто-то знает в чем проблема?
Ещё не могу разобраться как отключить сетку. Тут тоже нужна помощь. Заранее спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не знаю, как это устроено в figma, но нажмите f12 или правой кнопкой мыши и "исследовать элемент" (или что-то в этом духе), а сетка, кстати, полезная

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn В фигме такое не сработает.

Comment: спасибо. разобралась. нужно было выключить по итогу режим разраба и выключить сету, потом снова включить и тогда можно работать с элементами по отдельности

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей вот я об этом и подумал

Comment: @юля совет: скачайте какой-нибудь макет и сверстайте с изображения. Получите больше опыта

Answer (score 1):

нужно было выключить по итогу режим разраба и выключить сету, потом снова включить и тогда можно работать с элементами по отдельности